# Package restore failed ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, nuget, asp.net-core, dnx, dnu

I am experiencing an issue with **package restoring from NuGet** repository in Visual Studio 2015.

When I am creating a new ASP.NET 5 project the dependencies related to ASP.NET 5 don't seem to be downloaded and added to my new project and I get that exclamation mark in yellow triangle sign next to each reference, instead.[Solution Explorer.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vogDx.png) 
Well, obviously, I can't build a solution as the dependencies are highlighted red in **project.jason**. 
When I hit ***Restore Packages*** option in my *Solution Explorer* the packages don't get restored and I get that **Package restore failed** message. In the output I can see that it fails due to an exception **at** ***System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()***

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> **System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.**
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[Output window.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7jb6.png)

I am using latest DNX (1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr x64), in fact I've tried to use different DNXs none of them worked as it supposed to. Also I've tried to reinstall ASP.NET 5 bundle; to repair Visual Studio 2015; uninstalled and installed NuGet package manager in different ways; tried to delete **NuGet.Config** from *AppData\Roaming\NuGet*, manually deleted files from AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio; restored default settings, but none of the above solutions worked for me. 
The only "sort of fix" which did something for me was cmd prompt ***"dnu restore"*** command in project folder. It resolved my initial dependecies **"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler"** and **"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"** and I managed to build the project. I thought it would be it, but, in truth, it didn't do much: I am stil not able to add any new dependency, even if I type it in manually in **project.jason** the NuGet package manager fails when trying to resolve it.

---

The question is: has anyone experienced similar issues? How can I force NuGet manager to resolve ASP.NET 5 dependencies? 
Any advice is appriciated. Links to the articles, threads, comments are welcomed.

Comment: If you try to add a Dependency to the json file are you getting intellisense? Maybe this will help?
http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/

Comment: @juanvan the article you've provided certainly contain a valuable info, but unfortunately does not provide a solution to my problem. Yes, I do get intellisense when I type in new dependency into **project.jason**. But it gets highlighted red, as soon as NuGet tries to obtain it from repository. It says it is smth to do with cryptography 'System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.' and I don't have clue how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your development machine has the FIPS algorithm policy enabled and therefore labels this implementation of SHA256 as invalid. .NET does offer a FIPS compliant implementation: SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.

If you have no idea why your machine is set to be FIPS compliant, your administrator might be able to help you out. Since this can be a requirement or even regulation in your industry, I'd try to make sure. There are ways to disable the FIPS mode in case you're sure that you don't have to be compliant.

Comment: make sense. I will try to disable FIPS as soon as I get home

Comment: janpieter_z you were right, as soon as I disabled FIPS the NuGet manager started to pick up packages one after another. I don't know why this communication is labeled as invalid by FIPS, neither know I how critical is FIPS for the security, but NuGet package manager can stuck on restoring packages in ASP.NET. So I'll leave FIPS disabled for now, untill I find another solution if the one exists. Thank you, janpieter_z your help is much appriciated!

Comment: More than welcome! Reading a bit more up on FIPS probably wouldn't hurt ;)